# How to determine area of pixel in meters with GDAL and Python?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I have a raster loaded in Python using GDAL bindings.  I'd like to be able to determine the area of a pixel in meters although I'm not confident that the projection is in meters.  On [this](https://gdal.org/tutorials/osr_api_tut.html) page I see a reference to `OGRSpatialReference::GetLinearUnits()`, but no corresponding Python bindings.

Any suggestions on how I can determine the are of a pixel in meters?

*EDIT:* Here's an example of how to get at the linear units:

```
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.SetProjection(dataset.GetProjection())
print srs.GetLinearUnitsName(), srs.GetLinearUnits()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its definitely in there, I'm guessing its an oversight in the docs.  From osr.py:

```
    def GetLinearUnits(self, *args):
      """GetLinearUnits(self) -> double"""
      return _osr.SpatialReference_GetLinearUnits(self, *args)
```